# Where to find definition of ITU ZOnes / CIRAF zones

Tags: map, itu-zones

Writing Android logbook. Still in search for ITU zones map.
Best option would be GeoJSON with list of Polygons (one per zone)
Second best any list of zone border points for each zone.
Any help appreciated.

ITU just provides a picture of map, no waypoints, no polygons.

I can't use the pictures by https://g7vjr.org/2019/08/google-earth-kmz-files-for-cq-zones-and-itu-zones/ as these cann't answer "IS THIS POINT INSIDE ZONE X" because they are 70 intersecting lines each unrelated to any of 90 zone.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no single set of definitions that will serve ITU non-amateur radio purposes (whatever they may be) and specifically amateur radio uses (such as award rules; contest scoring). EI8IC writes about the background and provides some pointers and links at the bottom of his [ITU Zones Map](https://www.mapability.com/ei8ic/maps/ituzone.php) website.

Comment: TU. This is exactly why I'm looking not for descriptive (words, picture) but definitive model (GeoJSON, list of waypoints)...